# Rearranging Data Frame Long to Wide, combining several columns

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr

Let me start out by saying I am a complete beginner. So please bear with me if I lack the most basic terminology

Here's what I am trying to do:

```
test <- read.table(text = "Tube Window Session Value
                            A 1 1 13
                            A 1 2 14
                            B 1 1 17
                            B 1 2 14", header = TRUE)
```

to

```
result <- read.table(text = "Window Session Tube.A.Value Tube.B.Value
                            1 1 13 17
                            1 2 14 14", header = TRUE)
```

I searched for a bit and found the `tidyr` package. I am fairly certain that its `spread()` function is what I am looking for, but I can't get it to do what I need.

Comment: In English the word you're looking for 'reshaping', in 'old' R language you're looking for 'casting', and in 'new' R language (tidyverse) you're looking for 'spread'. The similar question (linked at the top) demonstrates various ways of doing this.

Comment: Thank you. I already found that answer. But it's not exactly what I am looking for, I think. It doesn't explain how you merge the  A, B and Value columns in my example into 2 new columns: Tube.A.Value and Tube.B.Value. Am I missing something?

Comment: using the `data.table` method (because I know this method better than the others, and I wrote the answer on that linked question), you can do `library(data.table);
setDT(test);
dcast(test, formula = Window + Session ~ Tube)`